# can't connect to development server when running react native app on nox emulator

Tags: android, react-native

have to say that running on a real devices works

so I tried the following things:

1. I ran `nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001`
2. I ran `react-native run-android`
3. the app installed on the device but didn't open the app
4. and navigated to http://192.168.14.130:8081/ with the browser on the emulator (192.168.14.130 -is my
   local ip)
5. opened the app and enabled hot reloading
6. reloaded and still got the error
7. tried restarting the app and navigating to the same url but nothing
8. tried navigating to `http://192.168.14.130:8081/index.delta?platfrom=android&dev=ture&minify=false` - but got `bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module AccessibilityInfo` ... `This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968`
9. did the steps mention but nothing
10. tried runing `react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001` instead of `react-native run-android`, nothing special happened

I have the following setup

- React Native version: 0.57.7
- OS: Windows 10
- Nox Player version: 6.2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

so I tried few more emulators: blue stacks 4 and andy

and with andy emulator it works like a charm, it has os 7.1.2, and nox player runs on 4.4, I think this is the reason why it works

[andy emulator](https://www.andyroid.net/)